# How can I sync two couples of columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time, jupyter-notebook

As you can see in the image, I have a table with 5 columns:
**AgTime**: *Aggregate Timestamp*
**AgCons**: *Aggregation Consumption*
**DvTime**: *Device Timestamp*
**DvCons**: *Device Consumption*
**filteredAgTimes**: *the distance of the nearest DvTime to the AgTime*. (I calculated this column using abs(AgTime - DvTime).min()

[image]

My goal is to subtract the Device Consumption from the Aggregate Consumption, but my problem is here that the timestamps of the Aggregate do not match the Device Timestamp. So I want to subtract the Consumption of the nearest timestamp of the device, from Aggregate Consumption.

I want to compare and subtract in this way:

[image]

I tried to do this using two **for** loops into each other but it wasn't over after 9 hours so it was computationally expensive. So that's not an option.

By the way, the number of AgTime records is about 13k where I have about 12k for DvTime. So I want to have a table like this (wherein DvTime column I have the closest timestamp to the AgTime column):

[image]

Please help me. Thank you!

**Update: some data as text (in csv format):**

```
AgTime,AgCons,DvTime,DvCons,filteredAgTimes
2014-07-13 12:00:11,180,2014-07-13 12:00:14,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:00:17,181,2014-07-13 12:00:22,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:00:23,181,2014-07-13 12:00:29,2.0,0 days 00:00:01
2014-07-13 12:00:29,181,2014-07-13 12:00:37,2.0,0 days 00:00:00
2014-07-13 12:00:35,182,2014-07-13 12:00:45,2.0,0 days 00:00:02
2014-07-13 12:00:41,185,2014-07-13 12:00:52,2.0,0 days 00:00:04
2014-07-13 12:00:47,181,2014-07-13 12:01:00,2.0,0 days 00:00:02
2014-07-13 12:00:53,181,2014-07-13 12:01:08,2.0,0 days 00:00:01
2014-07-13 12:00:59,183,2014-07-13 12:01:16,2.0,0 days 00:00:01
2014-07-13 12:01:05,182,2014-07-13 12:01:22,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:01:11,180,2014-07-13 12:01:29,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:01:17,181,2014-07-13 12:01:35,2.0,0 days 00:00:01
2014-07-13 12:01:23,180,2014-07-13 12:01:41,2.0,0 days 00:00:01
2014-07-13 12:01:29,181,2014-07-13 12:01:49,2.0,0 days 00:00:00
2014-07-13 12:01:36,180,2014-07-13 12:01:57,2.0,0 days 00:00:01
2014-07-13 12:01:42,183,2014-07-13 12:02:04,2.0,0 days 00:00:01
2014-07-13 12:01:48,183,2014-07-13 12:02:12,2.0,0 days 00:00:01
2014-07-13 12:01:54,180,2014-07-13 12:02:18,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:02:00,180,2014-07-13 12:02:26,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:02:06,180,2014-07-13 12:02:33,2.0,0 days 00:00:02
2014-07-13 12:02:12,180,2014-07-13 12:02:41,2.0,0 days 00:00:00
2014-07-13 12:02:18,184,2014-07-13 12:02:48,2.0,0 days 00:00:00
2014-07-13 12:02:24,181,2014-07-13 12:02:56,2.0,0 days 00:00:02
2014-07-13 12:02:30,180,2014-07-13 12:03:04,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:02:36,180,2014-07-13 12:03:10,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:02:42,180,2014-07-13 12:03:17,2.0,0 days 00:00:01
2014-07-13 12:02:48,180,2014-07-13 12:03:24,2.0,0 days 00:00:00
2014-07-13 12:02:55,179,2014-07-13 12:03:31,2.0,0 days 00:00:01
2014-07-13 12:03:01,181,2014-07-13 12:03:37,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:03:07,180,2014-07-13 12:03:45,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:03:13,182,2014-07-13 12:03:53,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:03:19,180,2014-07-13 12:03:59,2.0,0 days 00:00:02
2014-07-13 12:03:31,182,2014-07-13 12:04:06,2.0,0 days 00:00:00
2014-07-13 12:03:37,181,2014-07-13 12:04:14,2.0,0 days 00:00:00
2014-07-13 12:03:43,181,2014-07-13 12:04:22,2.0,0 days 00:00:02
2014-07-13 12:03:49,180,2014-07-13 12:04:27,2.0,0 days 00:00:04
2014-07-13 12:03:56,183,2014-07-13 12:04:35,2.0,0 days 00:00:03
2014-07-13 12:04:01,181,2014-07-13 12:04:43,2.0,0 days 00:00:02
2014-07-13 12:04:08,180,2014-07-13 12:04:49,2.0,0 days 00:00:02
2014-07-13 12:04:14,184,2014-07-13 12:04:57,2.0,0 days 00:00:00
2014-07-13 12:04:20,180,2014-07-13 12:05:04,2.0,0 days 00:00:02
```

Comment: Post some data as text.

Comment: @moys I just added the data to my post in csv format.